# sql server case for detect equal or not equal condition (mutually exclusive)

Tags: sql-server, case, mutual-exclusion, equals-operator

I need to do something like that:

```
select * from table1 where type case @param when 1 then EQUAL else NOT EQUAL end 3
```

select all for type = 3 or for type <> 3, depending param.
Considere a large select involving a lot of tables ....
The idea is not copy same select on both sides of "UNION"

```
select * from table1 where type = 3 and @param =1
UNION
select * from table1 where type <> 3 and @param <> 1
```

Is it possible?

Comment: can you give some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select * 
from table1 
where 
    ((@param=1) and (type=3))
or
    ((@param<>1) and (type<>3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
    type = 3 AND @param = 1
    OR type <> 3 AND @param <> 1
```

Use `SELECT DISTINCT *` if you require a result set without any duplicates.

Comment: this will not work without parenthesis, and (I think) DISTINCT is not needed

Comment: It will work fine without parentheses, and `DISTINCT` is to mirror the use of `UNION` in the question, though I also can't tell if that's a requirement.

Comment: I think that OP is not aware of difference between UNION and UNION ALL, and mixing AND/OR without parenthesis will lead to undesired results, in this case result all records will be returned or maybe none

Comment: I think you're right on the unions, however, `AND` is evaluated before `OR`, so my query will return the desired results.

Comment: you are right, working with different languages I am used to put always (Delphi evaluates AND/OR before =/<> ) parenthesis, in this case it works just fine

Comment: Jajaja, very easy!
Thanks a lot, it's slow but works. To build indexes!